# How to handle EOF with the scan_fmt crate?

Tags: input, rust

With the [`scan_fmt`](https://docs.rs/scan_fmt/0.2.6/scan_fmt/) crate, how do I handle EOF, when used with the `scanln_fmt` helpers? I want to do something like this where `x` is `None` if a empty line was provided:

```rust
let (isEOF, x) = scanln_fmt_some!("{d}");
```

How can I distinguish between empty new line input and EOF?

Comment: You can't, `scan_fmt` doesn't provide it. just use `std::io::stdin`

Comment: Yup, as of 0.2.6, ScanError always returns None for source() so there is no way to distinguish between EOF and other parsing errors.

Answer (score 0):

The scan_fmt crate does not expose a way to distinguish between EOF and other errors.

The macros only return either a `(Option<X>, Option<Y>, ...)` (as from `scan[ln]_fmt_some`) or a `Result<(X, Y, ...), ScanError>` (as from `scan[ln]_fmt`). And [`ScanError`](https://docs.rs/scan_fmt/0.2.6/scan_fmt/parse/struct.ScanError.html)'s contents seems to only explain what type failed to parse, but not why.